# How to generate Time based One Time Password(OTP) with Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am generating a random string as OTP using the following code -

```
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string

otp = get_random_string(6, allowed_chars='0123456789')
```

The problem with this is due to SMS delivery issues people request for a lot of OTPs and then when they arrive together they have no idea which one is currently valid.

I want to generate a OTP that wouldn't change for **30 minutes** and is unique for every phone number which would be something like **+919999999999**.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, especially as [TOTP has a published standard algorithm](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6238). Use an app like [`django-otp`](http://django-otp-official.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that has the correct implementations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to be deterministic, just integer divide the current timestamp by 30 minutes, concatenate that with the phone number and with a secret salt, then hash them all.

Alternatively you can generate a random one and store it in Django cache with an expiration duration of 30 minutes.